# Laravel redirect to specific route when user is not logged

Tags: php, laravel

If i go to http://www.yourdomain.com/admin/login i see my login page.

If i go to http://www.yourdomain.com/admin/example i have the redirect to http://www.yourdomain.com/login without the admin.

My web routes:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/login','Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/login','Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
    Route::get('/manifiesto','AdminController@getIndex')->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::get('/logout','Auth\AdminLoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
    Route::get('/trabajadores','AdminController@showTrabajadores')->name('admin.trabajadores');
    Route::get('/clientes','AdminController@showClientes')->name('admin.clientes');
    Route::get('/proyectos','AdminController@showProyectos')->name('admin.proyectos');
    Route::get('/administradores','AdminController@showAdmins')->name('admin.administradores');
});
```

When i put some url with the /admin before and user isn't logged, i want to redirect to /admin/login.

Thanks.

More info:

App/http/Controllers/Auth/AdminLoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;
class AdminLoginController extends Controller
{

    protected $loginPath = 'admin/login';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:admin', ['except' => ['logout']]);
    } 
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('backend.public.pages.login');
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
   {
       //validate the form data
       $this->validate($request, [
           'email' => 'required|email',
           'password' => 'required|min:6'
       ]);
       //attempt to log the user in
       if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)){
            //if successful, then redirect to their intended location
            return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
       }
       return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email','remember'));
   } 

   public function logout()
   {
       Auth::guard('admin')->logout();

       return redirect('/');
   }
}
```

App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuthenticate.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminAuthenticate
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
 {
    if ($this->auth->guest())
    {
        if ($request->ajax())
        {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect()->guest('admin/login'); // <--- here
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
 }
}
```

Comment: Try this `Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{....});`

Comment: Same problem, i have the redirect to /login

Comment: Is there other login routes or JUST `admin/login` ?

Comment: Just admin/login

Comment: Did you added this middlware to your `app/Http/Kernel.php` in the `$routeMiddleware` property ? if yes and it's like this `'adminAuth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AdminAuthenticate::class,` then you need to do like this `Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'adminAuth'], function() {....});`
    `

Comment: In `app/Http/Kernel.php` in `$routeMiddleware` i add this line:  ` 'adminAuth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AdminAuthenticate::class,` i change the middleware name in route group to adminAuth, my files names are: `app/http/controllers/auth/adminlogincontroller.php`, `app/http/controllers/admincontroller` and `app/http//middleware/adminauthenticate.php`. If i go to /admin/manifiesto i get redirect to /login, and if i go to /admin/login i have the error: `Class Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AdminAuthenticate does not exist` @Maraboc

Comment: My mistake add it like this `'adminAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuthenticate::class,` and try again :p

Comment: Same.. if i go to /admin/clientes i get redirect to /login and if i go to /admin/login error: `Undefined property: App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuthenticate::$auth`

Comment: I think you forgot to add `protected $auth;
    /**
     * Create a new middleware instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Factory  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }` in your created middleware !
 I asumed that you copied the content of existing `Authenticate` middleware :p

Comment: The problem is i don't have a "basic" authenticate middleware, so i create it new and i copy your code. Anyway, i found an easy way to access /admin/login and it's put it outside the group route. I try again and again go to /admin/clientes for example and get redirect to /login.. i can't understand it.

Comment: Do as i said in the previous comment and replace `return redirect()->guest('admin/login'); // <--- here` with `return redirect()->route('admin.login'); // <--- here`

Comment: Nothings new happen.. Same redirect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149687/discussion-between-maraboc-and-lluis-puig-ferrer).

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an middleware

```
php artisan make:middleware AuthAdmin
```

2. Check for guest in the `handle` method of the middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('admin/login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

3. Add a key to the middleware in `app/Http/Kernel.php` in `$routeMiddleware` array

```
'auth_admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthAdmin::class
```

4. Attach the `auth_admin` middleware to the group

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => 'auth_admin'], function() {
    // Your admin routes except login
});
```

Comment: If i replace my code for yours, i have the same error, all routes go to /login not /admin/login. And www.mydomain.com/admin/login redirect to /login too.

Comment: Same error. And if i put /admin/login error: Class 'App\Http\Middleware\Auth' not found

Answer (score 0):

write bellow code in your route.php file

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function() {
        Route::controller('login', 'AdminloginController');
    });
    Route::group(array('before' => 'admin_ajax', 'prefix' => 'admin'), function() 
    {
        //route for pages which are render after login
    });
    Route::get('/admin', function() {
        return View::make('admin.loginform');
    });
```

And Write bellow code in your filter.php file

```
Route::filter('admin_ajax', function() {
    if (!Auth::admin()->check()) {
        return Redirect::to('admin/login');
    } else {  
    }
});
```

And if you are using laravel 5.4

```
Route::get('/manage', function () {
    return redirect('manage/login');
});
Route::group(['prefix' => 'manage'], function() {
    //login bypass for the below listed controllers    
    Route::resource('login', 'AdminLoginController@showLoginForm');
    Route::post('dologin', 'AdminLoginController@login');
});
```

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.4 so i edit the first code in web.php and the second in which file?

Comment: If you are using laravel 5.4 then you have to define Middleware

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is add the `auth` middleware like this :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('/login','Auth\AdminLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
    Route::post('/login','Auth\AdminLoginController@login')->name('admin.login.submit');
    Route::get('/manifiesto','AdminController@getIndex')->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::get('/logout','Auth\AdminLoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
    Route::get('/trabajadores','AdminController@showTrabajadores')->name('admin.trabajadores');
    Route::get('/clientes','AdminController@showClientes')->name('admin.clientes');
    Route::get('/proyectos','AdminController@showProyectos')->name('admin.proyectos');
    Route::get('/administradores','AdminController@showAdmins')->name('admin.administradores');
});
```

But by default this will redirect to `/login`, if you want to override this you have two chocies depending on if you have other type of users that uses the `/login` route or not !!

- **If NO ONE uses `/login` route**

1- You need to modify `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::handle()` method and change `/login` to `admin/login`.

2- Then you need to add `$loginPath` property to your `\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController` class.

**Authenticate**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
class Authenticate {
        /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest())
        {
            if ($request->ajax())
            {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }
            else
            {
                return redirect()->guest('admin/login'); // <--- here
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**AuthController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    protected $loginPath = 'admin/login'; // <--- here

    // ... other properties, constructor, traits, etc 
}
```

- **If there is someone using `/login` route**

You must create you own [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#defining-middleware) and do what it takes for auth checking in the `handle` method with redirecting to your `admin/liging` route :)

In this case :

1. Add the following line in `$routeMiddleware` property at `app/Http/Kernel.php` file

   ```
   'adminAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\YourNewMiddleware::class,
   ```
2. Don't forget to add your new middleware in route group as follow

   ```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => 'adminAuth'], function() 
    {
       // your admin routes
    });
   ```

Comment: Hi maraboc, i edit my question with the info of the files you say in your answer. I have same error when i edit it.

Comment: Try with this `return redirect()->route('admin.login'); // <--- here` !!

Comment: no mate, didn't work. I just make it without middleware, i just check if guest is admin or just a guest. And redirect is working fine, but have other error. I post here the url of the other question. Thanks!

Comment: If you can, check chat @Maraboc

Answer (score 0):

Make an another middleware for admin. follow the step

1. Make a file named `AdminAuthenticate` in `app/Http/Middleware` location and copy the content of Authenticate in New file
   change the Class name as `AdminAuthenticate`
2. Change the content of handle function as show below

   ```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
   {
       if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
           if ($request->ajax()) {
               return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
           } else {
               return redirect()->guest('/admin/login');
           }
       }

       return $next($request);
   }
   ```
3. Add the following line in `$routeMiddleware` array at `app/Http/Kernel.php file`

   ```
   'AdminAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminAuthenticate::class,
   ```
4. Now everything is okay. just add your new middleware in route group as follow

   ```
   Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin',  'middleware' => 'AdminAuth'], function() 
   {
      // all admin routes
   });
   ```

   Or you can add new middleware to constructor function of every admin controller as like below

   `$this->middleware('AdminAuth');`

Comment: I edited my files, you can check in the answer. Same errors than before.

Comment: Please follow my answer carefully again. after completed middleware, add new middleware for admin panel. add $this->middleware('AdminAuth') in constructor of every admin controller @LluísPuigFerrer